# Eonasdan DatePicker not working in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datepicker, datetimepicker, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to use the package  [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#manual). I had already followed the installation tutorial. But I couldn't accomplish to get it to work. I imported the files required into `app\public`folder as well.

### My Folder Structure

[public folder structure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9alqjarm2t07i6/Snap%202018-02-07%20at%2019.01.19.png?dl=0)

### My blade file

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Laravel Bootstrap Datepicker</title>


    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- JS AND CSS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/moment.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js')}}"></script>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

    <body>
        <!-- DATATIME PICKER CODE -->
        <img src="{{asset('goku.jpg')}}" alt="Mountain View">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control " />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                            defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                            disabledDates: [
                            moment("12/25/2013"),
                            new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                            "11/22/2013 00:53"
                            ]
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

### My Result

The result I'm getting is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhjvtzzrzn2ddai/Snap%202018-02-07%20at%2018.24.56.png?dl=0), an import with a fail icon. And nothing showing up while clicking.

Comment: What is the structure of the `public` folder ?

Comment: The structure is like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/whblv9gv4n7964y/Snap%202018-02-07%20at%2018.48.55.png?dl=0)

Comment: Try to load css before js

Comment: I tried it but is not working.